# Can you have a DLL with administrator privileges that is linked from a client application with only user level privileges?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wmi, cryptoapi

I have a need both in C# and C++ where a Windows client application needs to do things like query WMI and access functions in the crypto API through a DLL.  Certain things such as accessing disk encryption status requires administrator access.  Is it possible for the DLL to have administrator access privileges where the linking client remains at user level privileges ?  If so, how would I go about doing this ?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to turn off UAC. Otherwise, you need to have the code executed in another process, because access checking is per process. One way is to use a COM interface that Microsoft provides for that purpose. Sorry I forget its name but you can google it. Another and probably much easier way is to just fire up another process.

Comment: Oh, I googled it for you. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: So that sounds like the other process (that would be providing the functionality of the DLL) would be running as a service.  Am I interpreting that correctly ?

Comment: I think a service (in the sense of Windows service) would just complicate tings. However, you COULD make an out of process COM server, and have that running elevated. There are just many ways to do this. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestions.  It appears I have a lot to explore !

Answer (score 1):

No, code itself does not have Windows privileges.

As pointed out in comments you can use 2 processes running under different accounts (which immediately adds plenty of interesting issues how to communicate between two).

Or you can impersonate account with your code, but Windows permissions would apply to any code that runs while impersonating and not to just code from particular native DLL/.Net assembly.